# MVC core script files not rendering on server

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using ASP.NET Core 2.0 MVC in Visual Studio. My `.js` files are working in IIS Express when I debug in Visual Studio, but when I deploy either to IIS on `localhost` or to a live server, those scripts are not rendering .

My startup file has

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseMvc();
```

I have included the script file in the `.cshtml` file like this

```
<script src="~/assets/views_js/Welcome/Index.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
```

This is the html rendered from the server

```
<script src='/bcc/assets/views_js/Welcome/Index.js'></script>
```

Comment: I have also tried to run it in both debug and release version

Comment: when i press `cnt+u` to view the source i can see the script tag in the source but if you click on the script tag you will get a 404 indicating tht the file did not load

Comment: this is the html rendered from the server   
`<script src='/bcc/assets/views_js/Welcome/Index.js'></script>
`

Comment: i just realized that the issue is caused by the fact that some files are not all deployed when using the file publish method. How do i make sure that all the files will be  published?

Comment: not all the files in wwwroot are being published. how do i make sure that all files and folders in wwwroot are published?